# How do I create a dict of {str, [list of str]} by looping over a list of str?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

Need help with a restaurant recommender project as part of a class.

I have a list of strings/values and I would like to create a dict of {str, list of str} by looping over it. Here is the list of strings/values:

```
contents_list_2 = ['Georgie Porgie', 87, '$$$', 'Canadian,Pub Food', 'Queen St. Cafe', 82, '$', 'Malaysian,Thai', 'Dumplings R Us', 71, '$', 'Chinese', 'Mexican Grill', 85, '$$', 'Mexican', 'Deep Fried Everything', 52, '$', 'Pub Food']
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary that uses the $ as the keys and uses the restaurant names as values. For example:

```
{'$': ['Queen St. Cafe', 'Dumplings R Us', 'Deep Fried Everything'],
 '$$': ['Mexican Grill'],
 '$$$': ['Georgie Porgie'],
 '$$$$': []}
```

I have tried using the zip() function, but it doesn't capture all the restaurant values:

```
price_to_name = dict(zip(contents_list_2[2::4], contents_list_2[0::4]))
print(price_to_name)
>>> {'$$$': 'Georgie Porgie', '$': 'Deep Fried Everything', '$$': 'Mexican Grill'}
```

I think the challenge comes from adding a list of values per key...I've tried various things with limited success. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is in chunks of 4, the easiest solution is probably to just loop it:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

contents_list_2 = ['Georgie Porgie', 87, '$$$', 'Canadian,Pub Food', 'Queen St. Cafe', 82, '$', 'Malaysian,Thai', 'Dumplings R Us', 71, '$', 'Chinese', 'Mexican Grill', 85, '$$', 'Mexican', 'Deep Fried Everything', 52, '$', 'Pub Food']
price_to_name = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(0, len(contents_list_2), 4):
    price_to_name[contents_list_2[i + 2]].append(contents_list_2[i])

price_to_name = dict(price_to_name) # get rid of default value
print(price_to_name)
```

Comment: Or just loop over the `zip` the OP did, and use that to populate the `defaultdict(list)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the strings come in groups of four where the 1st one in the group is the name and the third one is that $ rating, you could do this

```
content = ['Georgie Porgie', 87, '$$$', 'Canadian,Pub Food', 'Queen St. Cafe', 82, '$', 'Malaysian,Thai', 'Dumplings R Us', 71, '$', 'Chinese', 'Mexican Grill', 85, '$$', 'Mexican', 'Deep Fried Everything', 52, '$', 'Pub Food']

ratings = { rating:[N for N,R in zip(content[::4],content[2::4]) if R==rating]
                   for rating in ("$","$$","$$$","$$$$") }

print(ratings)

{'$': ['Queen St. Cafe', 'Dumplings R Us', 'Deep Fried Everything'],
 '$$': ['Mexican Grill'],
 '$$$': ['Georgie Porgie'],
 '$$$$': []}
```

Answer (score 0):

[A `collections.defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is the solution here. You just need to explicitly loop over your `zip`-ed data and `append` instead of assigning:

```
from collections import defaultdict  # At top of file

price_to_name = defaultdict(list)
for price, name in zip(contents_list_2[2::4], contents_list_2[::4]):
    price_to_name[price].append(name)
```

This keeps the work `O(n)` (`O(n)` for each slice, another `O(n)` to loop over them, average-case/amortized `O(1)` for lookup and `append` respectively, which is still `O(n)` overall).

If the `name`s might be duplicated, and order of the names doesn't matter (and/or membership testing efficiency is important), change `list` to `set` and `append` to `add`.

Technically, you could do this with a regular `dict` and do `price_to_name.setdefault(price, []).append(name)` instead, but that needlessly creates an empty `list` over and over. Membership testing or `try`/`except KeyError` also works, but `collections.defaultdict` is just the simplest, fastest and most obvious solution.

Comment: Thank you. When I add print(price_to_names), the output I get is: `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'$$$': ['Georgie Porgie'], '$': ['Queen St. Cafe', 'Dumplings R Us', 'Deep Fried Everything'], '$$': ['Mexican Grill']})`. Why does it have the extra "defaultdict(<class 'list'>...etc)" ?

Comment: @YogeshRiyat: Because it's a different class type, not plain `dict`. If you want to have it be a plain `dict` after population (so subsequent accesses don't autovivify missing keys with a new `list`), you can just do: `price_to_name = dict(price_to_name)` after the loop completes to initialize a plain `dict` with the current state of the `defaultdict`. Normally, you don't print raw objects except for debugging purposes, so whether or not it's a `defaultdict` is more about whether you want auto-vivication in the future.

Comment: I am now trying to create cuisine_to_names. ```for i in contents_list_2[3::4]: # Take , out of cuisine element
    contents_list_2[3::4] = [i.split(',') if ',' in i in contents_list_2[3::4] else i for i in contents_list_2[3::4]]``` But I get errors with default dict now because the third element is a list now. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to make this more clear in the original post under "part 2"

Comment: @YogeshRiyat: When you have a new question that's not incredibly similar to the original problem, ask a new question for that specific problem. You're making your question too broad and invalidating good answers by adding new questions days after the fact.